# In TSX file : Property 'createRef' does not exist on type 'typeof React'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I need the reference of the component. Just shifted from jsx to tsx and can't find a solution for this problem.

Other workaround would be to use query selector but that's not a good way of doing things in react I believe.

Here is the constructor function

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: initialData,
        showNewListForm: false,
        whichButtonClicked: undefined,
        background: props.background || "#23719f"
    };

    this.divContainerRef = React.createRef();
    console.log("kanban reference : " + React.createRef().current);

    this.handleDragStart = this.handleDragStart.bind(this);
    this.handleDragEnd = this.handleDragEnd.bind(this);
    this.handleLaneDragEnd = this.handleLaneDragEnd.bind(this);
    this.handleLaneDragStart = this.handleLaneDragStart.bind(this);
    this.onCardAdd = this.onCardAdd.bind(this);
    this.onCardClick = this.onCardClick.bind(this);
    this.addNewListHandler = this.addNewListHandler.bind(this);
    this.containerRefResolver = this.containerRefResolver.bind(this);
    this.isBoardPresent = this.isBoardPresent.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Have you imported `React` correctly?

Comment: import * as React from 'react';

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have an out of date version of `@types/react`. The latest version `16.3.14` has type definitions for `createRef`.

Comment: Bingo !!! Your solution worked mate ! Thanks a lot. 

I was meddling with the code and found one more solution, a workaround , (React as any).createRef() worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my Typescript codebase I had to update react-dom types:

`yarn upgrade @types/react-dom^16.3.0`

Comment: There is no tagged version of react-dom type present on npm or yarn for 16.3.0.

Comment: you're right. I assume yarn resolved it to the next semantic version up